# Downloaded Kubuntu 12.10 and installed Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, 12.10, kubuntu

I wanted to install Kubuntu 12.10 from USB on a brand new computer, with no OS.
I downloaded the file and started the computer with the USB.
It installed Ubuntu 11.10.
Why and how can I change that?

Comment: Where did you get the image from?

Answer (score 2):

I can only assume that you have inadvertently downloaded the wrong image. My advice would be to download the appropriate image from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/12.10/release/) and reinstall.

P.s Welcome to Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You probably downloaded wrong image.

You can either download the right one as Chris said, OR you can simply upgrade.

- Open dash and find **Update Manager** (I don't remember how exactly
  it's called). Check for updates and you will be suggested to upgrade
  your distribution.
- After upgrading you will have the latest Ubuntu version.  Now you need to install package **kubuntu-desktop** . Simply open **Terminal** (Ctr+Alt+T) and paste this line:

  sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
- Enter your password when prompted.
- When prompted select **kdm** display manager (or you can stay with lightdm - it's your choice).
- After it's done - reboot and select KDE or Kubuntu when logging in.